# Open the file by searching tag in vim

Tags: vim

I want to search a tag in vim's bottom bar and open the file which has the specified tag. `ctrl-p` takes filename but not the tag. Is there any plugin that can do this?

Comment: Try `:CtrlPTags foo` and `:help ctrlp`.

Comment: I am getting 'Triling characters" error. I did set tags=/home/tags

Comment: It's `:CtrlPTags<CR>` then `foo`.

Comment: You can also use the `:tag` command. e.g. `:tag foo`. Better yet you can search for the tag like so: `:tag /foo`. Combine this with tab completion and you can go very far w/o any plugins. Side note: `<c-]>` goes to the tag under the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

There's a builtin extension that does this for you.

```
 let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['tag']
```

If you add that to your vimrc, on next vim startup, you'll be able to hit `Ctrl+B` to change to the `tag` tab and do your tag search that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) [plugins](https://github.com/vim-scripts/taglist.vim) that can do the job.
I am using [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) :

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>: open the file at the line where the symbol is defined
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: make you jump back to the previous file you were

It can also be done via `Cscope`